# Django-models ForeignKey Objects display Field Name instead of Object Values

Tags: django, django-models

I am using a ForeignKey called Memberno in My Django models. After entering data in the Members Class, it appears in the other classes as "member object" in the 'memberno' field. For ForeignKey, I am using 'raw_id_fields' as a workaround, but for normal fields and even 'filter_horizontal' , each memberno value is displayed as "member object".  I would like the values  to appear as they are in the member class i.e. 1, 2, ...

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Members(models.Model):
    DESIGNATION_CHOICES=(
    ('ADM', 'Administrator'),
    ('OFF', 'Club Official'),
    ('MEM', 'Ordinary Member'),
    )
    memberno = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    sname = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    onames = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField()
    phoneNumber = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    regNo = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=3,choices=DESIGNATION_CHOICES)
    image = models.ImageField(max_length=100,upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True, null=True)
    course = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)


def __unicode__(self):
    return  u'%s %s %s' % (self.fname, self.sname, self.memberno)


def get_absolute_url(self):
    return '%s%s/%s' % (settings.MEDIA_URL, settings.ATTACHMENT_FOLDER, self.id)

def get_download_url(self):
    return '%s%s/%s' % (settings.MEDIA_URL, settings.ATTACHMENT_FOLDER, self.name)




class Security(models.Model):
    memberno = models.ForeignKey(Members, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=70)

def __unicode__(self):
    return  u'%s %s %s' % (self.username, self.password, self.memberno)


class Subscriptions(models.Model):
    memberno = models.ForeignKey(Members)
    receiptNo = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date = models.DateField()
    amount = models.FloatField(max_length=99)

def __unicode__(self):
    return  u'%s %s %s' % (self.receiptno, self.type, self.memberno)




class events(models.Model):
    eventName  = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    eventID =  models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    details = models.TextField()
    attendanceFee = models.FloatField(max_length=99)
    date = models.DateField()
    memberno = models.ManyToManyField(Members)



def __unicode__(self):
    return  u'%s %s %s' % (self.eventName, self.eventID, self.memberno)
```

Comment: Need to format the source code so that it is legible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The admin interface appears to use `__str__()` to determine the display of a model.  I make it a habbit to always define both `__unicode__()` and `__str__()` when I create a model.  For example:

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    activity_code = models.ForeignKey(ActivityCode)
    note = models.TextField(blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return "(%s) %s" % (self.activity_code.short, self.note)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'(%s) %s' % (self.activity_code.short, self.note)
```

**Update:**
It looks as though your `def __unicode__(self)` is not indented properly in your code.  As a result it is not a part of your class, and is not being used.  Indenting is very important in Python.

Comment: Well, I have read somewhere that def __str__ is discouraged as it may result in some errors that cause Python to crash

Comment: Well if I change `__str__()` to return "FindMe", it shows up in the list of `Activity` object.  If I change `__unicode__()` to "FindMe", it shows up in the drop down for other objects which have a `ForeignKey` to `Activity`.  It may be discouraged, but it works.

Comment: I changed to 


def __str__(self):
 return "(%s)" % (self.memberno)

but it still doesn't show the values

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect the lack of indention.  In order to be a part of a class, the methods must be indented into the class' code block.  Your `get_absolute_url` method is probably failing too.

Comment: I decided to abandon this class in favour of Django's built in user class. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I understand your question completely, but have you defined a [unicode](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/models/instances/#unicode) method for your models?

Comment: class events(models.Model):
     eventName  = models.CharField(max_length=25)
     eventID =  models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
     details = models.TextField()
    attendanceFee = models.FloatField(max_length=99)
    date = models.DateField()
    memberno = models.ManyToManyField(Members)

    def __unicode__(self):
  return  u'%s %s %s' % (self.eventName, self.eventID, self.memberno)
 

My problem is that memeberno will display "member Objects " in place of each object instead of the actual objects like "1", "2" , "3" etc.

Comment: gramware, you will need to define a `unicode(self)` method for the `Members` class as well.

Comment: its already there 

class Members(models.Model):
 DESIGNATION_CHOICES=(
 ('ADM', 'Administrator'),
 ('OFF', 'Club Official'),
 ('MEM', 'Ordinary Member'),
 )
 memberno = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
 fname = models.CharField(max_length=15)
 sname = models.CharField(max_length=15)
 onames = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
 email = models.EmailField()
        ....
 image = models.ImageField(max_length=100,upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True, null=True)
 

def __unicode__(self):
 return  u'%s %s %s' % (self.fname, self.sname, self.memberno)

Comment: That is insanely hard to read, can you post that in your question?